# Spark file cleansing and transformation

Tags: apache-spark

```
I have a file with 5 columns tab separated value (tsv). I need to do data scrubbing and transformation. 
case 1) Remove the special character (\001 and \x0D ) with "" 
case 2) Filter rows which has less then 5 columns count as Bad_Row RDD
case 3) Iterate Bad_Row RDD and check if last character of row is "\n" then remove last character "\n" and append next row until we get column count 5 
Sample File Formate
------------------------------
one two 12345   four    five
aaa ppp 12345   ttt 
bbb
ccc rrr 12355
yyy
ddd
eee iii 12845   rrr     two

Good_Rows RDD
-------------------------------
one two 12345   four    five
eee iii 12845   rrr     two

BAD_Row RDD
-------------------------------
aaa ppp 12345   ttt 
bbb
ccc rrr 12355
yyy
ddd
```

Remove "\n" from second line and append third line into second line and recalculate column count if column count is 5 then consider as good_row and into   Good_Rows RDD.

### Sample Code Snippet

```
def FilterData(rdd):
    row=rdd.split("\t")
    col_count=len(row)
        if col_count!=5 :
            return row


textFile1=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/A/test.tsv")
Clean_RDD=textFile1.map(lambda x: x.replace("\\001|\\x0D",""))  # case 1
Badrow_RDD=Clean_RDD.map(FilterData) # case 2
```

Please help to implement case 3

```
Thanks 
Vishal
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for your 3rd problem in Scala.

```
val data=sc.textFile("file:/home/rieter/Test_Streaming/ab.txt").map(x=>x.split(" +").map(x=>x.trim)).filter(x=>(x.size<5)).flatMap(x=>x).collect
 val data1=data.take(data.length-(data.length%5))
 data1.splitAt(5)
```

Output

```
   scala> data1.splitAt(5)
   res59: (Array[String], Array[String]) = (Array(aaa, ppp, 12345, ttt, bbb),Array(ccc, rrr, 12355, yyy, ddd))
```

Comment: Thanks Ishan 

Provide solution is working but I have 10 millions of record in the file so collect and take is not optimize to use

Can you suggest other alternate 

data1.splitAt(5)  // this we can store as RDD